# Check if a given string is a exponential and then check if it is a whole number?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to build an application. I have a entry box which when i get the value it returns a string.

where, n_term= entry variable

I can check if it is a integer or not, by using: 'try: str.isdigit(n_term)...',

is there a similar function to check if when user enters a exponential in a string form, eg. "2e5", it checks if it is a whole number.

Test data: "2e5", "2.222e2"

where:
"2e5" = true as 2e5 == 2x10^5 == 200000, a integer 
"2.222e2" = false as 2.222e2 == 2.222x10^2 == 222.2, a float

Comment: There is no such function. For not too large exponents (positive or negative) you can try `float(n_term) == int(float(n_term))` but I guess that is not reliable.

Comment: You can use the Python function [is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
def is_whole(n):
    try:
        return float(n) == int(float(n))
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Exponential strings can be converted to float. You can then check if that float value is the same as its int value. The `except` is there in case the user enters an invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [float.is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) function to check if a float is a whole number.

> Return True if the float instance is finite with integral value, and False otherwise:

To check if string s is an integer:

```
float(s).is_integer()    # Is True/False based upon float being a whole number
```

Examples:

```
print(float("2e5").is_integer())       # Output: True
print(float("2.222e2").is_integer())   # Output: False
print(float("-2.222e5").is_integer())  # Output: True
print(float("-2.222e2").is_integer())  # Output: False
```